# Oracle - need to extract money like 59,432,000 $ between given strings

Tags: oracle, extract, currency

I'm trying to do a regex match to return a substring.  From this string:

```
TK 19120226477558So tien GD:+50,000,000
```

I would want to return the results: `50,000,000`

From this string:

```
TK 22010000631740 tai +5,854 VND vao 23:59 25/01/16;
    so du TK tai 08:01 26/01/16 la: 5,336,331 VND.ND: Lai tien gui KKH
```

I would want to return the results: `5,854` and `5,336,331`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you alredy tried?

Comment: regular expressions require defined and reliable patterns.  In your case it's not enough to identify repeating numbers: you need to filter the clumps of numbers which aren't your results.  This means you need to define the patterns which precede and follow your desired results.  You haven't provided enough samples for us to do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL can get the result that has at least one comma ',':

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('so du TK tai 08:01 26/01/16 la: 5,336,331 VND.ND: Lai tien gui KKH', '\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+') FROM DUAL;
```

But if the result you want to get is less than one thousand like '789', the pattern('\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+') is not correct.

It should need a more complex pattern. But your rule in the case is not very clear.

Comment: I have quick test, regex expression in oracle you suggest to me look good, many thanks! I see more case